# Alpine js not defind type

Tags: javascript, php, expression, alpine.js, uncaught-exception

Im trying to build out the second part of this tutorial https://joeyfarruggio.com/wordpress/skeleton-loader/.
First part is working well, however now i try and add the second part for a load more button, im starting to get a few errors that im trying to fix.

on page load im seeings

> cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: category is not defined
> at [Alpine]  category == 835 ? 'active' : '' (eval at  (cdn.min.js:5:665), :3:33)
> at cdn.min.js:5:1068
> at fr (cdn.min.js:1:6642)
> at cdn.min.js:5:31317
> at r (cdn.min.js:5:16370)
> at Object.Zr [as effect] (cdn.min.js:5:16158)
> at N (cdn.min.js:1:398)
> at cdn.min.js:1:511
> at Function.xn (cdn.min.js:5:31311)
> at r (cdn.min.js:5:2273)

and on category click, im getting

> Alpine Expression Error: filterPosts is not defined

Expression: "filterPosts(835)"

<a hreff @click=​"filterPosts(835)​" class=​"active">​cat b​​
te @ cdn.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
fr @ cdn.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
o @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ cdn.min.js:5

This is the code i have tried, I cant see why category is not defined and filterPost not defind. Ive been at this hours any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php /* Template Name: test */ 
?>
<html>
<head>
     <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
     <script>

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
posts: null,
    category: null,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,
    loading: false,
    offset: 0,
    loadingNew: false, // <--- defaults to false
    loadingMore: false, // <--- defaults to false

filterPosts(id) {
    this.loadingNew = true;
    this.showFiltered = true;
    this.category = id;
    this.offset = 0; // <-- reset offset to zero
    this.fetchPosts();
},
    
    loadMore() {
    this.loadingMore = true;
        this.offset += 10;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.fetchPosts(true);
},

// append defaults to false 
    fetchPosts(append = false) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "ajaxPosts");
        formData.append("offset", this.offset); // <-- Add new data to the form

        ...

        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            if (append) {
                // Appends posts to the end of existing posts data
                this.posts = this.posts.concat(res.posts);
            } else {
                // Resets the posts data with new data
                this.posts = res.posts;
            }

            this.loading = false;
        });
    },
    getTotal() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("action", "filterPosts");

    fetch(adminURL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
        this.total = res.total;
    });
},

init() {
    this.getTotal();
}
}));
})

    
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div x-data="filterPosts('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>')">
        
        
<section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?> <?php theme_section_attr_class('main-section js-posts') ?>>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading mx-0">
      <?php $before_title = get_sub_field('before_title');
      if ($before_title) : ?>
        <strong class="sub-title"><?php echo $before_title ?></strong>
      <?php endif ?>
      <?php $title = get_sub_field('title');
      if ($title) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>

      <div class="head js-posts-search-text">
        <?php if ($search_value) : ?>
          <h2 class="h5 fw-semibold"><?php printf(__('Showing results for “%s”', 'base'), $search_value) ?></h2>
        <?php endif ?>
      </div>
      
<!--alipne js dynamic post start-->
    <div class="has-filter row flex-md-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 js-posts-holder">
                <!-- Posts Column -->
            <div x-show.important="showDefault" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                <!-- Default posts query -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/posts-filter/default-query' ); ?>
            </div>
             <!-- Load More Posts -->
  <!-- Load More Posts -->
<div @click="loadMore()" x-show="total > (limit + offset)" class="text-center mt-12">
    <button class="border border-solid border-slate-700 text-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-800 px-4 py-2">
        Load More
    </button>
</div>
                <!-- Filtered posts -->
            <div x-show.important="showFiltered" x-html="posts" class="row cards-area js-posts-items">
                <!-- Default posts query -->
            </div>
            
             <template x-if="loadingNew || loadingMore">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            <template x-for="i in 4">
                <div>
                    <div class="h-52 w-full bg-slate-200 rounded-lg"></div>
                    <div class="h-8 w-1/2 bg-slate-200 rounded-lg mt-4"></div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
        </div>
                
        <!-- Filtered posts -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
             <aside class="sidebar">
                 <div class="widget widget-filter">
                     <button class="widget-title">Explore Topics</button>
                     <svg class="separator" viewBox="0 0 238 11" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <line opacity="0.3" y1="0.5" x2="101.942" y2="0.5" stroke="#3CD5AF"></line>
                <line opacity="0.3" y1="10.5" x2="237.5" y2="10.5" stroke="#3CD5AF"></line>
              </svg>
            <?php 
                $categories = get_categories();
                if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) : 
            ?>
            <ul class="filter-list">
                <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
                
                // Skip "Uncategorized" category
                if ($category->name == 'Uncategorized') continue; ?>    
        
                   <li :class=" category == <?php echo $category->term_id; ?> ? 'active' : ''">
            <a hreff="" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name ); ?></button>
        </li>
                
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
</aside>
        <!-- Filtered end -->
          </div>   
    </div>
    </div>
<!--alipne js dynamic post end-->

</section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```